# angularjs + get multiple checkbox value and attribute values

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to get the multiple checkbox value and attribute values.

Each checkbox have multiple attribute values(data-id, data-ot,data-si).

How to get the checked checkbox with 3 attribute values.

```
<table>
    <thead class="search">
        <tr>
            <th>
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectall " ng-model="selectall" ng-click="select(data)">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td>
            <input data-id="287" data-ot="31" data-si="541" type="checkbox" - ng-model="rowselect">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td>
            <input data-id="295" data-ot="331" data-si="31" type="checkbox"  ng-model="rowselect">
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td>
            <input data-id="297" data-ot="321" data-si="31" type="checkbox"  ng-model="rowselect">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td>
            <input data-id="296" data-ot="451" data-si="671" type="checkbox"  ng-model="rowselect">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td>
            <input data-id="293" data-ot="91" data-si="651" type="checkbox"  ng-model="rowselect">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td>
            <input data-id="294" data-ot="13" data-si="14" type="checkbox"  ng-model="rowselect">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" ng-click="ShowSelected()" />
```

Expected output:

For example 2 checkbox selected selected means:

```
[{"id":"xx","ot":"xx","si"},{"id":"xx","ot":"xx","si"},]
```

Code:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ShowSelected = function() {
     ///
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in keeping your data inside attributes like that unless that is something you specifically need for some particular reason.

The easiest way to do this is to make an object array on your scope like this:

```
$scope.data = [
  {id: 123, ot: 234, si: 567, checked: false},
  {id: 321, ot: 243, si: 789, checked: false},
  {id: 345, ot: 678, si: 567, checked: false}
];
```

Then you can use ng-repeat to create the table and bind the checkboxes to the `.checked` property:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <!-- your table header -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in data">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="element.checked">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then write the `showSelected()` function:

```
$scope.showSelected = function(){
  var tempArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].checked) tempArray.push(data[i]);
  }
  return tempArray; //or maybe console.log(tempArray) or encode to JSON etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute 'checked' to your checkbox model

```
$scope.checkboxList = {[
    {
        "id": "xx",
        "ot": "xx",
        "checked": false
    },
    {
        "id": "xx",
        "ot": "xx",
        "checked": false
    }
]}
```

Use `ng-model` in your html to bind to your checked attribute

```
<tr ng-repeat="checkbox in checkboxList ">
     <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox.selected"></td>
     <td>{{checkbox.ot}}</td>
</tr>
```

And in your controller you can use `$filter` to filter your checkboxes

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.ShowSelected = $filter('filter')($scope.checkboxList , { $: true });
});
```